# Behavior of map and flatMap with decimal point

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce, flatmap

Consider this dataset of movie rating (userId,movieId,rating,timestamp)

```
1,1,4.0,964982703
1,3,4.0,964981247
1,223,3.0,964980985
1,231,5.0,964981179
1,1226,5.0,964983618
6,95,4.0,845553559
6,100,3.0,845555151
6,102,1.0,845555436
6,104,4.0,845554349
6,105,3.0,845553757
6,110,5.0,845553283
6,112,4.0,845553994
610,152081,4.0,1493846503
610,152372,3.5,1493848841
610,155064,3.5,1493848456
610,156371,5.0,1479542831
610,156726,4.5,1493848444
610,157296,4.0,1493846563
610,158238,5.0,1479545219
610,158721,3.5,1479542491
610,160080,3.0,1493848031
610,160341,2.5,1479545749
610,160527,4.5,1479544998

m = sc.textFile('movies/ratings_s.csv')
```

For a rating histogram, I understand that we can do as follow

```
scores = m.map(lambda line : line.split(',')[2])
sorted(scores.countByValue().items())
```

> [('1.0', 1), ('2.5', 1), ('3.0', 4), ('3.5', 3), ('4.0', 7), ('4.5',
>   2), ('5.0', 5)]

I tried flatMap just to understand the difference :

```
scores = m.flatMap(lambda line : line.split(',')[2])
sorted(scores.countByValue().items())
```

The result that I had was

> [('.', 23), ('0', 17), ('1', 1), ('2', 1), ('3', 7), ('4', 9), ('5',
>   11)]

Could you help explain the behavior of flatMap here :

1. What is the logic that flatMap is doing ? What does it "flatten" to create such result?
2. Why does it strip "." separately and keep only the integral part ? We are not asking to split with "."
3. How should I get back the decimal results with .5 score ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the logic that flatMap is doing ? What does it "flatten" to create such result?

[flatMap](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=flatmap#pyspark.RDD.flatMap) takes a function that returns a "collection" (e.g. a list).  It's essentially equivalent to performing a `map` to return the collection which is further `flattened` into its individual elements.  In your `flatMap` example, function `lambda line : line.split(',')[2]` transforms each line into the 3rd split-string, which (being viewed as a collection of characters) is then `flattened` into individual characters.

> Why does it strip "." separately and keep only the integral part ? We are not asking to split with "."

Since the result of the `flatMap` are now a list of individual characters of the 3rd split-string of every line, `countByValue()` will count each of the numeric digits and decimal points (as characters), hence the reported result.

> How should I get back the decimal results with .5 score ?

If you want to use `flatMap` to produce the same result as your `map` version:

```
m.map(lambda line : line.split(',')[2])
```

you would need to make the lambda function return a proper collection of the selected split strings, like:

```
m.flatMap(lambda line : [line.split(',')[2]])
```

Comment: Thanks @Leo. I will try later when getting back home but I am throwing the follow-up questions here : 1. Could we say that if I force it to be numeric _m.flatMap(lambda line : float(line.split(',')[2]))_  we no longer have a _list of characters_ ? 2. If I use the first column userId, map and flatMap will produce same result since it is numeric ?

Comment: @Kenny, 1. `m.flatMap(lambda line : float(line.split(',')[2]))` would crash since a float cannot be treated as a collection, but 
`flatMap` requires a function that returns one.  Again, you can make `flatMap` work by changing the lambda function to return, say, `[float(line.split(',')[2])]`.  2. Yes, it's up to you to target any of the split-items.  `flatMap` will work as long as the given lambda function has the right signature.

Answer (score 0):

What is the logic that flatMap is doing ? What does it "flatten" to create such result?

Answer - line.split(',')[2] returns a string. Flatmap flattens the string (when you flatten a string, you will get charecters because string is a combination of chars) i.e, creates charecters out of the string that’s why you see one charecter in the output.

Why does it strip "." separately and keep only the integral part ? We are not asking to split with ".”
Answer - The answer above explains why ot strip “.”

How should I get back the decimal results with .5 
score ?
Answer - again, above answer should explain what you need to do. For dealing with numbers, you can map further from string to number and then calculate.

Please accept answer if it solves.